# Function reading file

Tags: c++, ifstream

It supposed to read from a file and store in my class variable. But function ain't reading. Where is problem here ?

```
void GetGameInfo (const string fv, GetInfo G[], int & questionN)
{
    string gameSection, gameDificulty;
    int gameNumber;
    ifstream fd(fv);
    while(fd != 0)
    {
        fd >> gameSection >> gameDificulty >> gameNumber;
        G[questionN].takeGame( gameSection, gameDificulty, gameNumber);
        fd.ignore(100, '\n');
        questionN++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `while(fd != 0)` to `while(fd.good())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be reading like following

```
while ( fd >> gameSection >> gameDificulty >> gameNumber )
{
   //...

}
```